# append decimal point in the middle of integer in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, decimal

I'm doing a report from our database regarding some amount

It shows like this in the report from the front end

[image]

however in the backend it's like this

[image]

It seems that the system adds a decimal point before the last two digits of the entries I've check the other ones and this seems to be the case

My question is, is there a function that I can use to append a decimal point before the last two digits whenever I generate the report in postgres?or is there another way to achieve the same result?

So I can provide a backend report that shows the same as the front end

Comment: Well, this totally depends on the software that generates that report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `amount` values are actually in cents, you should be able to just divide by 100:

```sql
SELECT expense_date, CAST(amount / 100.0 AS money) AS money
FROM yourTable;
```

Also, you may wish to handle this formatting issues in your presentation layer rather than directly on Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea it is indeed in cents though I had a problem with the script above as its output after the decimal point was .00  I played around with it and I came up with this which gives the output I'm looking for

Comment: `Select id,expense_date ,   cast(round( CAST(amount::float8 /100 as numeric), 2)as money ) as Amount from expense_requests`

Comment: @jemacosta08 If you use `CAST(amount / 100.0 AS money)` you might be able to avoid the explicit cast.